# Finding a solution of partial derivative of a standard derivative

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Considering the formula mentioned below, I arrived to the expansion as stated after performing a partial derivative with respect to the x co-ordinate:

$$\nabla \left({\frac{dB}{dt} B}\right) = \frac{dB}{dt}\frac{\partial B}{\partial x} + B \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{dB}{dt}\right)$$
where, $B(t, x)$.

This expression comes from a paramagnetic particle moving through a time-variant magnetic field $\frac{dB}{dt}$, which is created using $n$ number of magnets (with magnetic field strength $B$) oriented in alternating polarity. The motion of the particle is rotatory and changes only in the $x$-direction, hence the $y$ and $z$ component for the partial derivative is ignored. Therefore, the $x$ motion can be considered as a linear motion rather than rotatory. Hence, the partial derivation can be done in the Cartesian co-ordinate (or at least that was my line of thought).

Now, my question arises from obtaining an answer for the second part of the expansion $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{dB}{dt}\right)$. Can someone please explain to me how a partial derivative of a standard derivative can be solved? I tried to explain in as much detail as I could, but let me know if any further information is required.

Answer (score 1):

Physicists have a real talent for mucking things up with notation.

When you write $\frac{d B}{dt}$, what you really mean is this:

You have a time varying magnetic field, at all points in your space, however many dimensions that may be. The magnetic field vector, at the point $\boldsymbol x$, and the time $t$, is equal to $\boldsymbol B(t,\boldsymbol x)$. This function is of *two* variables, so writing $\frac{dB}{dt}$ is ill-defined. However, if we introduce a particle, traveling in such a way that it is at the position $\boldsymbol x$ at the time $t$, then the magnetic field vector at the location of the particle, at the time $t$, is
$$\boldsymbol B(t,\boldsymbol x(t))$$
This quantity depends *only* on $t$, so considering $\nabla\big( \boldsymbol B(t,\boldsymbol x(t))\big)$ doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. It makes sense to consider $x$ dependant on $t$ and that the magnetic field vector $B$ should be considered solely as a function of time. However, I still have some doubt regarding the final sentence. Considering that case, I am a bit lost as to how I should approach with solving the problem. I reached the $\nabla \left({\frac{dB}{dt} B}\right)$ expression from Maxwell's third Law (Faraday's Law of Induction). If you need more details, about how I came about this expression, I can explain it to you.

Comment: Braniac, please do.